# Annoying memory leak (kind of) problem when adding new instances of an object to a collection

Tags: c#, websocket

I have this annoying issue adding a new instance of an object to a collection, which is overriding the properties of another instance of the object in the same collection. I have never seen this before so it's very odd!

The object is a client I have written for Holochain and so includes a websocket for talking to holochain (an exe running over websocket RPC).

So I think it has something to do with the runtime keeping hold of refs to the 1st object?

So I guess I am kind of attempting to implement some kind of connection pool? Because this is an admin app that allows multiple clients to connect to the admin connection over websocket.

So is there a better way to implement this? I just need a way to keep a collection/list of the client connections (instances of my HoloNETClient (that in turn wrap a WebSocketClient).

```
private List<HoloNETClient> _holoNETappClients = new List<HoloNETClient>();

HoloNETClient newClient = CreateNewAppAgentClientConnection(e.Port.Value);

newClient.Connect();
_holoNETappClients.Add(newClient);

private HoloNETClient CreateNewAppAgentClientConnection(ushort port)
{
    
    HoloNETClient newClient = new HoloNETClient(new HoloNETDNA()
    {
        HolochainConductorAppAgentURI = $"ws://127.0.0.1:{port}"
    });

    newClient.OnConnected += _holoNETClientApp_OnConnected;
    newClient.OnReadyForZomeCalls += _holoNETClientApp_OnReadyForZomeCalls;
    newClient.OnZomeFunctionCallBack += _holoNETClientApp_OnZomeFunctionCallBack;
    newClient.OnDisconnected += _holoNETClientApp_OnDisconnected;
    newClient.OnDataReceived += _holoNETClientApp_OnDataReceived;
    newClient.OnDataSent += _holoNETClientApp_OnDataSent;
    newClient.OnError += _holoNETClientApp_OnError;

    newClient.HoloNETDNA.AutoStartHolochainConductor = false;
    newClient.HoloNETDNA.AutoShutdownHolochainConductor = false;

    //These properties override all previous items added to the _holoNETappClients List. 
    newClient.HoloNETDNA.AgentPubKey = CurrentApp.AgentPubKey; 
    newClient.HoloNETDNA.DnaHash = CurrentApp.DnaHash;
    newClient.HoloNETDNA.InstalledAppId = CurrentApp.Name;

    return newClient;
}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Can you please de-clutter your example code and leave only the code that's actually relevant? _"which is overriding the properties of another instance of the object in the same collection"_ - which ones? We only know what you tell us.

Comment: Done, hope that is clearer? :)